# pg_search for an advanced search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pg-search

I'm trying to figure out how to pass multiple parameters to my search using pg_search_gem and the pg_search_scope

This is my simple search

```
include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :simple_search, against: [:title, :description], using: { tsearch: { dictionary: "spanish"} } 

def self.search(search)
    if search.present?
        simple_search(search)
    else
        find(:all)
    end
end
```

But now I'm trying to do something like this

```
include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :simple_search, against: [:title, :place, :category], using: { tsearch: { dictionary: "spanish"} } 

def self.searchadv(title, place, category)
  simple_search(:title => title, :place => place, :category => category)
end
```

I know this is totally wrong but this is my inquiry.

---

UPDATE

here is the new code

```
  pg_search_scope :advance_search, lambda {|*args, query|
      return {:against => args,
      :query => query,
      using: { tsearch: { dictionary: "spanish"} } }
  }

def self.searchadv(query, title, place, category)
    advance_search(:all, :title => title, :place => place, :category => category)
end
```

Still not working. But it's almost done! I'm getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic search scopes](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#dynamic-search-scopes)

```
include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :simple_search, lambda do |query, *args| 
    return { :against => args, :query => query }
  end

def self.searchadv(query, title, place, category)
  simple_search(query, :title => title, :place => place, :category => category)
end
```

Comment: Done, but now I hace another problem. I update my code, could you check it please.

Comment: you're not passing in the search query to the searchadv method, which in turn should pass it to the `advance_search` scope

Comment: I updated the code, but now I'm getting this error: wrong number of arguments (3 for 4)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why I have to pass the query parameter, because I call searchadv from my controller and my controller didn't know what is the query parameter. Please help me to understand

Comment: the query parameter is whatever you're trying to search. You can name it `search` like in your simple example. The error you're getting is because you didn't use the code like I showed you. You changed the order of the parameters. The variable length parameters must come last: `query`, then `*args`, not `*args, query`.

Comment: Mihai I still have the same error with the wrong number of arguments (3 for 4) please help me.

Answer (score 1):

4 years ago and I'm looking for the answer of this question. So, here is what I found and it works. Maybe it'll help someone:

I'm passing 2 arrays to the search scope, one with the columns and other with the queries. So you'll be able to add as many columns and queries as you want.

```
include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :advanced_search, (lambda do |args, query|
    return {
      :against => args, :query => query
    }
  end)

Model.advanced_search([:name, :current_status, :user_id],
            [params[:q_name], params[:q_status], params[:q_user]])
```